# Sendmessage to set a date in a sysMonthCal32 form?

Tags: c#, winapi, sendmessage, spy++

I'm using the windows API to set textboxes in another program... everything's working perfectly fine except for one edit, linked to a button which creates a sysMonthCal32 form...

It will be more clear with some snapshots:

the Edit (textbox with the button):

[image: edit]

Once the button clicked, the form SysMonthCal32 appears (in spy++ too):

[image: cal]

My code is the following first I try to send the message in the Edit (id'd by spy++ but it doesn't work), then I try it via the sysMonthCal32:

```
                    //birthdate
                    string bd = dd  + "/"+ mm +"/"+ yyyy;
                    child = FindWindowEx(parent, child, "Edit", null);
                    lExStyle = (long)GetWindowLong(child, GetWindowLongParam.GWL_STYLE);
                    lExStyle &= ~(ES_UPPERCASE);
                    lExStyle &= ~(ES_READONLY);

                    SetWindowLong(child, GWL_STYLE, (uint)lExStyle);

                    DateTime dt = new DateTime(int.Parse(aaaa), int.Parse(mm), int.Parse(jj));
                    //SendMessage(child, DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME, IntPtr.Zero, dt.ToString()); //<-- doesn't work (child is the textbox)
                    btn = FindWindowEx(parent, btn, "Button", null); //<-- I find the button
                    SendMessage(btn, BM_CLICK, IntPtr.Zero, "0, 0"); //<-- I click it to make the sysMonthCal32 form appear.

                    IntPtr cal = FindWindow(null, "SysMonthCal32"); //<-- i find the form
                    //SendMessage(cal, DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME, IntPtr.Zero, dt.ToString());
                    //doesn't work
                    SendMessage(cal, WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, bd); //bd= birthdate, doesn't work
```

I tried a lot found on the internet with no results... maybe someone has a solution here?

Here are differents snapshots of spy++:

Styles of the Edit:

[image: style]

After sending the msg to the Edit, though it remains blank, i got this on spy++:

[image: spy]

Styles of the SysMonthCal32 form:

[image]

Comment: The recommended way of doing this is by using the `System.Windows.Automation` namespace.

Comment: Wrong message, you need MCM_SETCURSEL.  The lparam is the hard one, that pointer needs to be valid in the process you are automating.  Which requires VirtualAllocEx and WriteProcessMemory.  Yes, you'd better use an UI Automation library.

Comment: Thanks. Have U more details about that Automation library? I've looked on the internet but found nothing really clear about it... Thanks!

Comment: I took a quicker solution: I launched an AutoIt script (compiled) in my C# program with the date as parameter ... and it worked perfectly fine... not a "clean" solution but a working one... thank you all!